# How do I compare two columns for matching and non matching values and get it in the format that I want?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, power-query

How do I find matching and non matching values between two columns and format it in the below manner?

Input:

```
| expected | match | forward | backward | actual |
|----------|-------|---------|----------|--------|
| a        |       |         |          | b      |
| b        |       |         |          | c      |
| c        |       |         |          | r      |
| d        |       |         |          | s      |
| e        |       |         |          |        |
```

Output:

```
| expected | match | forward | backward | actual |
|----------|-------|---------|----------|--------|
| a        | b     | a       | r        | b      |
| b        | c     | d       | s        | c      |
| c        |       | e       |          | r      |
| d        |       |         |          | s      |
| e        |       |         |          |        |
```

`forward` - present in `expected` but not in `actual` (`SQL left outer join`)

`backward` - present in `actual` but not in `expected` (`SQL right outer join`)

`expected` is what I get from an `SQL` query. I have a lot of scenarios when I don't have the `actual` column in the RDBMS, so I would have to use excel to compare. I can compare it usually using `VLOOKUP` but it is time consuming and also it does not give the format I want. I would like a solution which can be done **importantly** with format as above.

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Refer this link,,https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask and Edit you post also add Tag SQL or SQL Query.

Comment: you can use power query to replicate sql joins

Answer (score 1):

[image: Layout]

Assuming your information is layed out like above, you can use the following three formulas in C3, D3, and E3 respectively:

```
C3
=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$3:$B$7)/(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7,$F$3:$F$7)>0),ROW(A1))),"")

D3
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$3:$B$7)/(COUNTIF($C$3:$C$7,$B$3:$B$7)=0),ROW(A1))),"")

E3
=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$3:$F$7)/((COUNTIF($C$3:$C$7,$F$3:$F$7)=0)*($F$3:$F$7<>"")),ROW(A1))),"")
```

copy the formulas down through row 7 and you will wind up with the following:

[image: POC]

Note:  `AGGREGATE` performs array like calculations for function 15.  As a result do not use full column reference within the `AGGREGATE` function.  Restrict it to being close to your data set.  If not you can bog down your computer with a tremendous amount of calculations on blank cells.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Can you please add VBA and power query way of doing this also to your answer? Just curious :)

Comment: Just tried for one column. Man it's super intensive for my computer. I have 20k records (expected) and 21k records (actual)

Comment: I do not know power query, and am I not strong on VBA.  My advice would be to add power query and  excel-VBA tags to your question.  The reason why it would be bogging down is that the ARRAY like part AGGREGATE is having to calculate through 20K row in each cell where the formula shows up.  so if you copied it down say 100 rows, that is 2 Million calculations at least

Comment: @ForwardEd,, nice one it's working ☺

Answer (score 0):

For Power Query your key transformation would be **Merge Queries**. It is similar to a SQL join and uses similar terminology.  First step would be to build separate Queries for the **expected** and **actual** columns. For the **match** list I would build a Query using the Join Type = Inner. For the **forward** list I would build another query using Join Type = Left Anti, then one more for **backward** using Right Anti.

Pulling it all together exactly how you presented it would be a bit fiddly (if that is really necessary), but I imagine you could add an Index to each Query and use Merge Joins (Join Type = Left Outer) on the Index columns to get a single result from each Query on each row.